# Counting variable-stored elements in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

The value in the XML for `D_Payment_Amount_1` passed to the XSLT is a 401KL deduction amount.  Each record may or may not pass a value.  This sets the variable amount in the XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="counter3" select="Export/Record[ (D_Payment_Amount_1 > 0) ]"/>
```

I can't quite figure out what is being put into the variable since the `select` is `T` or `F` test.  Further on in the code there is a test (`<xsl:if test="count($counter3) > 0">`).

I guess what's confusing me is the name of the variable, `$counter3`.  If the data amount is greater than 0, is the amount being loaded into the variable or is a 1 (basically a count) being added?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't quite figure out what is being put into the variable since the `select` is `T` or `F` test.

No, the `select` XPath will set `counter3` to the node set (XSLT 1.0) or sequence (XSLT 2.0 and up) of `Record` elements with an `Export` parent (immediately beneath the current node) and a `D_Payment_Amount_1` child whose value is greater than 0.

Then, `count()` will return the number of those `Record` elements so that the `xsl:if` can conditionally execute its code when that count is greater than 0.

The `counter3` variable is poorly named.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I presume then that the actual value that is loaded in the variable is the specific payment amount.  Somewhere along the way I will need to sum these values so that is why I needed to know the actual value of the variable.  Thanks again, Greg

Comment: With further investigation of the existing code (not mine) I realized that for my project I will not need a counter just a way to sum the actual amounts.  Thanks again for your help, it really helped me to clarify what I need to do now.  Greg Gregerson